# How can I make in Kivy Spinner change source of the Image by clicking on value?

Tags: python, kivy, spinner, python-3.7

Want to make simple App with many pictures in it.
Can't understand how to define it in main.py.
I'm stuck with Spinner button events on_release. 
This code what I've tried to do but it doesn't work for me.

file main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass    


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):


        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

Code of test.kv:

```
<Container>:
    Spinner:
        text: "Map"
        values:"Main plan","Center", "Block A", "Block B", "Block C"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 155, 44
        pos:2,333

        #on_release: values=("Main plan").imageplan.source='400px.jpg' 
        #on_release: values=("Center").imagecenter.source='center.jpg'
        #on_release: values=("Block A").imageblocka.source='blocka.jpg'

        Image:
            id:imageplan
            source:'mylogo.png'
            size:100,100
            size_hint:None,None
            pos:200,200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DictProperty` to relate the values of the `Spinner` with what will be shown in the `Image`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Container(BoxLayout):
    options = DictProperty(
        {"Main plan": "400px.jpg", "Center": "center.jpg", "Block A": "blocka.jpg"}
    )


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

```
<Container>:
    Spinner:
        id: spinner
        text: "Map"
        values: root.options.keys()
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 155, 44
        pos:2,333

        Image:
            id:imageplan
            source: root.options.get(spinner.text, "mylogo.png")
            size:100,100
            size_hint:None,None
            pos:200,200
```

Comment: Wow, it's fantastic! So fast!
I don't even know what to say. It's an honor for me.
Thanks man, it's works for me:)